# Product subcat with duplicate name of a subcat of another cat gets the category name in the slug

Tags: hierarchical

Suppose the following categories tree in Woo:

```
Men (slug men)
-- Shoes (slug shoes / was created first)
Women
-- Shoes (slug shoes-women / was created second)
```

Why is this happening? Both subcats belong to different categories. Why is the category slug appended to the name of the second *duplicate* subcat?

And anyway, for whatever reason Autommatic decided to program it that way, I need to change it, as the nature of the e-shop I'm building is full of such *duplicate* subcat names, as it will sell clothing, and there will be the same subcat and even subsubcat names for many categories (Men, Women, Kids, etc)...

Any insight on this?

Comment: (Congrats on asking a WooCommerce question that's actually about core WP function, BTW - almost nobody manages that. Unless it turns out it is Woo that's breaking this!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me two days to figure this out in the proper way, so I'll add it here for anyone else that may need it in the future.

```
add_filter('wp_unique_term_slug', 'prevent_cat_suffix', 10, 3);
function prevent_cat_suffix($slug, $term, $original_slug)
{
    if ($term->post_type == 'product' && $term->parent !== 0) {
        return $original_slug;
    }

    return $slug;
}
```

As you can see in the code, I've narrowed it down to products only, but you can make it suitable for any other post type also by removing the `$term->post_type == 'product' &&` in the code above.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the proper way to fix that - you're just undoing what wp_unique_term_slug() has done. [Here's the code that's supposed to allow duplicate slugs across taxonomies](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/5.8.1/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2938-L2941) - I'd work out why that isn't working here.

Comment: Yeah, the part you highlighted is supposed to allow the term to be "duplicate" as long as it belongs to another parent. But in practice it's not. Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of time, nor is it my job actually to investigate why it's not working (maybe a bug? although it looks fine). That's why I resourced in "undoing", as you said, what it's supposed to do. And TBH, the way I see it, I didn't undo it; in fact I made sure it does what it was originally supposed to do; that is to allow duplicate subcats to exist as long as they are children of different cats.